# I am using SDL and this function cause my program to use all of my memory

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-ttf

I am a beginner to C++ and this function cause the memory of my program to continuously raise.

It's called in a while loop and it never stop.

```
void text_box()
{
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE1 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #1" , noir );                     
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE2 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #2" , noir );
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE3 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #3" , noir );
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE4 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #4" , noir );
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE5 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #5" , noir );
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE6 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #6" , noir );
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE7 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #7" , noir );
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE8 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #8" , noir );
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE9 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #9" , noir );
    SDL_Surface *MESSAGE10 = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  "Ligne #10" , noir );
    apply_surface( 0, 403, MESSAGE1, SCREEN );
    apply_surface( 0, 412, MESSAGE2, SCREEN );
    apply_surface( 0, 421, MESSAGE3, SCREEN );
    apply_surface( 0, 429, MESSAGE4, SCREEN );
    apply_surface( 0, 438, MESSAGE5, SCREEN );
    apply_surface( 0, 447, MESSAGE6, SCREEN );
    apply_surface( 0, 456, MESSAGE7, SCREEN );
    apply_surface( 0, 465, MESSAGE8, SCREEN );
    apply_surface( 0, 474, MESSAGE9, SCREEN );
    apply_surface( 0, 483, MESSAGE10, SCREEN );
}
```

It raise in a linear way until there is no more memory left.

Answer (score 2):

`TTF_RenderText_Solid` [returns a pointer to a *new* SDL_Surface.](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_43.html)

You need to [free](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FreeSurface?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) this surface when you're done with it.

In this particular case, since your text never changes, and I'm guessing `font` and `noir` are fixed, you could initialize MESSAGE1 through MESSAGE10 once, and reuse them, as suggested by Bartlomiej Lewandowski below.  Then you only need to free the surfaces if you reach a part of your program where they're no longer needed for display.

Comment: or even better, make it once and pass it as a parameter

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski : And what parameter would that be?  I don't see an `SDL_Surface *` parameter in the API.

Comment: I mean, pass it along to his `text_box()` function. The text does not change, so there is no need to generate a new surface in each loop.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski : Ah, good point. Allocate the surfaces once, and destroy them only when there's no longer any reason to display them.